# Difference between 2 DateTimes in Hours in Decimal Format

Tags: php, time

I have 2 DateTimes, I need to calculate the difference between them in hours **in decimal format**. The hard part is making sure the result is storing the value to 2 decimal places.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2017-09-01 23:00:00");
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$difference = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
```

But the result is just a whole number which loses too much accuracy for me. How to keep the value to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I assume `5.x`, but would help with the answer due to changes with `DateTime` object. Also any context on what you're wanting to accomplish with the precision/end-result would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime::diff` returns [`DaterInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) that has a whole number for each individual time related property.

The `days` property does not account for increments less than a day, as they are accumulated to and removed from the lesser properties and then is rounded down.

So `$diff->h` will never be greater than `23`. While `$diff->s` and `$diff->i` will never be greater than `59`. Where days will contain the total days within the `year` and `month` properties. Not to be confused with `$diff->d`, which is the incremental number of days.

In order to determine the total hours using diff, you just need to perform math on each of the properties to retrieve the number of hours of the property.

Example: https://3v4l.org/KhBQC

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-09-01 23:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-09-02 01:34:00');
$diff = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$hours = round($diff->s / 3600 + $diff->i / 60 + $diff->h + $diff->days * 24, 2);
echo $hours; //2.57
```

In php 7.1 you can also account for `microseconds` by adding `$diff->f / 3.6e+9`.

---

A more simplistic approach would be to subtract the unix timestamps, to retrieve the total number of seconds between the two dates. Then divide the remaining seconds by the number of seconds in an hour (3600).

Example: https://3v4l.org/SbjEU

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-09-01 23:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-09-02 01:34:00');

$hours = round(($datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp()) / 3600, 2);

echo $hours; //2.57
```

Comment: Either way works, one could also use `DatePeriod` to retrieve the seconds between the two dates and perform the same operation. https://3v4l.org/P0kJG

Answer (score 2):

2 decimal places:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2017-09-01 23:00:00");
$datetime2 = new DateTime();

$epoch1 = $datetime1->getTimestamp();
$epoch2 = $datetime2->getTimestamp();

$diff = $epoch1 - $epoch2;

echo number_format( $diff / 3600, '2' );
```

Comment: As a heads up, the current equation will result in a negative value. The later date operand should precede the earlier date operand to retrieve a positive value. Like so:  `$diff = $epoch2 - $epoch1;`  https://3v4l.org/ViMDa